# Convert URI to URL

Tags: php, html

How to convert an URI to URL if I know the current site path?

Consider these examples:

Current path is: `http://www.site.com/aa/folder/page1.php

Uri: folder2/page.php

Uri: /folder2/page.php

---

And what if the current path is:

`http://www.site.com/aa/folder/

or

`http://www.site.com/aa/folder

What the URLs will look like then?

I know this should be easy and obvious, but I can't find anywhere the complete answer (and yes, I did searched on Google)

Comment: "URI" is a hipster term (and has been superseded by IRI anyway), which refers to structuring identifiers. What you have there are path fragments. You might try "base_url", but a universal solution is likewise hard to google.

Comment: Well it depends on what results you want to have in the end. `/folder2/page.php` would be `http://www.site.com/folder2/page.php` and `folder2/page.php` would be `http://www.site.com/aa/folder/folder2/page.php`. So the question is what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: URLs are a subset of URIs. You can't convert from one to the other. Something is either a URI, a URI and a URL, or neither. It *looks* like your question is "How do I resolve a relative URI?", but your question really isn't clear.

Comment: @mario: Afaik the differences between URI and IRI is just the range of characters. The structure is the same so for this question IRIs are irrelevant. And they are URIs: *relative* URIs.

Comment: I'm reading a remote site with curl, and I need to determine the URLs for the relative links on several websites, so I can't control those links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a block of code that has the function that you need:
http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#76682

Edit: The above linked function modified with an example

```
<?php

var_dump(resolve_url('http://www.site.com/aa/folder/page1.php','folder2/page.php?x=y&z=a'));

var_dump(resolve_url('http://www.site.com/aa/folder/page1.php','/folder2/page2.php'));

function unparse_url($components) {
    return $components['scheme'].'://'.$components['host'].$components['path'];
}

/**
 * Resolve a URL relative to a base path. This happens to work with POSIX
 * filenames as well. This is based on RFC 2396 section 5.2.
 */
function resolve_url($base, $url) {
        if (!strlen($base)) return $url;
        // Step 2
        if (!strlen($url)) return $base;
        // Step 3
        if (preg_match('!^[a-z]+:!i', $url)) return $url;
        $base = parse_url($base);
        if ($url{0} == "#") {
                // Step 2 (fragment)
                $base['fragment'] = substr($url, 1);
                return unparse_url($base);
        }
        unset($base['fragment']);
        unset($base['query']);
        if (substr($url, 0, 2) == "//") {
                // Step 4
                return unparse_url(array(
                        'scheme'=>$base['scheme'],
                        'path'=>$url,
                ));
        } else if ($url{0} == "/") {
                // Step 5
                $base['path'] = $url;
        } else {
                // Step 6
                $path = explode('/', $base['path']);
                $url_path = explode('/', $url);
                // Step 6a: drop file from base
                array_pop($path);
                // Step 6b, 6c, 6e: append url while removing "." and ".." from
                // the directory portion
                $end = array_pop($url_path);
                foreach ($url_path as $segment) {
                        if ($segment == '.') {
                                // skip
                        } else if ($segment == '..' && $path && $path[sizeof($path)-1] != '..') {
                                array_pop($path);
                        } else {
                                $path[] = $segment;
                        }
                }
                // Step 6d, 6f: remove "." and ".." from file portion
                if ($end == '.') {
                        $path[] = '';
                } else if ($end == '..' && $path && $path[sizeof($path)-1] != '..') {
                        $path[sizeof($path)-1] = '';
                } else {
                        $path[] = $end;
                }
                // Step 6h
                $base['path'] = join('/', $path);

        }
        // Step 7
        return unparse_url($base);
}

?>
```

Comment: Also instead of my very basic unparse_url above, the comment on the php.net site recommends using the glue_url function from here (rename it to unparse_url: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#77053

Answer (score 2):

The `$_SERVER` superglobal will have the information you're looking for, namely `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` might also be useful.

Please see:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Actually this is for an external web page, not for my own script. So I'm reading a remote site with curl, and I need to determine the URLs for THEIR URIs

Comment: That's a whole different question than the one you asked. As dnagirl stated, you can use parseurl() but that will not guarantee you correct results. Without knowing their url structure, we can't help you much further.

Answer (score 0):

php has `pathinfo()`, `realpath()` and `parseurl()` and other filesystem and url path functions. Used together with info from the `$_SERVER` superglobal (as mentioned by andre), you should be able to do what you need.

Comment: Those functions can't help me, I have already read their documentation. I need something like getFullUrl($URI, $currentPath)

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = "http://www.site.com/aa/folder/";

$url = explode("/", $uri);
$url = $url[2];

echo $url; //www.site.com
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I need to get the full path, not the domain name. Unfortunately, it's not that easy, Michael Petrov's answer is the best by now

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you install PECL `pecl_http`, you can make use of `http_build_url`:

```
http_build_url("http://www.site.com/aa/folder/page1.php",
                 array("path" => "folder2/page.php"));
```

and you pass any of your relative URI(L)s as `path`. The function will make sure to build the correct one.